# How to animate the ordering in a random way on accelerometer change?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7.1

In a Grid of Images i want to animate the ordering in a random way on the change of accelerometer. Any idea on how can i go about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    Accelerometer mAccelerometer = new Accelerometer();
    mAccelerometer.ReadingChanged += OnAccelerometerReadingChanged;
    mAccelerometer.Start();
}

void OnAccelerometerReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerReadingEventArgs args)
{
    RandomizeYourViewModel();
}
```

Ofcourse you should have some kind of check for the values as acc is very sensitive. Also you should have VM that holds the list of images that are then bound to your view, so when you change the images list, the view will respond appropriately. As an addition you can also create Storyboards on the fly, to indicate change.